# Correlation analysis with dichotomous variables

Tags: correlation

Could correlation analysis with Pearson correlation or Spearman rank correlation be done between continuous variable and categorical dichotomous variable  eg, presence or absence of hypertension? My understanding is that correlation analysis is performed between two continuous variables but I found in some published studies that they do correlation analysis between dichotomous variables and continuous variables using Spearman rank correlation.